# How to enable gzip on a Nginx web server?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, svg, nginx, gzip

I tried to enable gzip on my website but with not good results.
Checking with http://checkgzipcompression.com/ gzip shows enabled but when I go to https://gtmetrix.com/ to test my website's performance and speed it seems that gzip is not enabled for some files (eg. JavaScript files and SVG files).

What am I doing wrong?

In order to enable gzip I used an .htaccess and pasted the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Before **mod_deflate.c** I also tried the following code too:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.* 
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

**Server Information**

```
server  nginx
vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 4):

NGINX does not have support for *.htaccess* files.

> **[Like Apache: .htaccess](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/)**
>
> You can't do this. You shouldn’t. If you need .htaccess, you’re
>   probably doing it wrong.

In order to enable Gzip compression on your NGINX web server, first open your NGINX's default configuration file: `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, and replace the existing Gzip settings with the following:

**nginx.conf** *(you can modify the settings below according to your needs)*

```
  # Enable Gzip
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    text/x-component
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml;

  gzip_static on;
  gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;
```

**Restart NGINX**

`service nginx restart` **or** `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

**NGINX Gzip documentation :** http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html